# Android spinner on dialog crashes if the spinner is open (list up) and you rotate the device

Tags: android, dialog, rotation, spinner, android-alertdialog

I have a Dialog with a couple of buttons and a spinner that seems to work fine except my app crashes under the following circumstances:
 1. start activity
 2. show dialog with Activity::showDialog (gets created in onCreateDialog)
 3. click on the spinner so that it shows the list
 4. spinner puts up an AlertDialog
 5. rotate the device 
 6. crash with IllegalArgumentException

I can see that the Activity has gone away and also that my Dialog has gone away but the AlertDialog put up by the Spinner remains. I would just dismiss the Spinner AlertDialog but it is a private member of the Spinner class (I checked the Android source code) so there is no way to access it.

If you move the Spinner to the Activity you get:
 1. start activity
 2. click on spinner so that it shows the list
 3. spinner puts up an AlertDialog
 4. rotate the device
 5. spinner AlertDialog disappears
 6. activity is shown rotated

I can only conclude that either:
 1. you are simply not supposed to put a spinner on an Dialog (or AlertDialog), or
 2. there is a bug in Dialog or Activity

Does anyone has any wisdom on this issue?

Comment: stack trace? sounds like you are trying to do something with a null variable after onRestore.

Comment: `Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalArgumentException)) 
 ViewRoot.doDie() line: 2695 
 ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1970 
 ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
 Looper.loop() line: 144 
 ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4937 
 Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
 Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521 
 ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868 
 ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
 NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]`

Comment: Sorry the backticks do not seem to have preserved the newlines. I worked around the issue by locking the screen orientation but clearly that is a dirty hack and only masks one manifestation of the problem. The Spinner AlertDialog may well be trying to access the original Activity (before the rotation) but as it is a private member it is hard to see what to do. Next step is to dig through the Activity and AlertDialog code but I do not have time at the moment.

Comment: Whats happening around line 1970? You're trying to pass in a variable with the wrong type.

Comment: Its hard to tell what is happening around line 1970 as it seems to be buried in the Android message loop. I think the AlertDialog that belongs to the Spinner is being orphaned when the Activity is torn down for rotation. I am just going to avoid Spinners on Dialogs, they are ugly anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest, add this to the declaration of your activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: This does not solve the actual issue. It is a workaround. Not a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with PopupWindow. The solution is to call

```
popup.dismiss()
```

in the onDestroy() method.